# How to create a website with 'infinite' scrolling space?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have an idea for a website but I am not yet sure on how to achieve the desired result. The end product would be a website where a series of visible connected nodes are generated based on data that comes back from a database.

The first concern is that I will need the website to accommodate any generated content which could span in any direction.

So does anyone know how to achieve an 'infinite' scrolling website? I have seen this kind of thing for online idea boards where the user can move their mouse in any direction and the page begins to scroll, with the page expanding seemingly infinitely.

Comment: This is a pretty vague question, but perhaps D3.js might be what you're looking for? https://d3js.org/

Comment: Are you meaning like in old Age of Empires games where you move the cursor to the edge of the screen to get the view port to move in that direction? (Sorry for the game reference, couldn't find a better way to explain it)

Comment: Yes I suppose so a good example! (And one I appreciate). I can start from a particular point and scroll around to see more content, but in a Web browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
// Fetch variables
var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var bodyHeight = $(document).height() - windowHeight;
var scrollPercentage = (scrollTop / bodyHeight);

// if the scroll is more than 90% from the top, load more content.
if(scrollPercentage > 0.9) {
    // Load content
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer that's a great place to start with the mechanics of it!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that strikes my mind on the concept of infinite scrolling is Facebook! The page at qnimate might be the code you are looking for -

[qnimate.com/facebook-style-infinite-scroll](http://qnimate.com/facebook-style-infinite-scroll/)

For infinity scrolling in either direction you will have to tweak the code to include `window.pageXOffset`

Other links that I would recommend checking out is -

[sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/)

[tutsplus.com/articles/vertical-and-horizontal-scrolling-with-fullpagejs](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/vertical-and-horizontal-scrolling-with-fullpagejs--cms-24215)

Comment: Brilliant, I could load it in asynchronously then blend it in with some effects. Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Bigglesworth Good Luck! :-)